# With condition on linear functional f and g such that whenever $f(x)\geq 0$ then $g(x)\geq 0$ how to conclude about kernel of both?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

> V is finite dimensional vector space with $f,g$ are non zero linear functional with property that
>   whenever $f(x)\geq 0$ then $g(x)\geq 0$ then show that
>
> 1) Ker $f\subset$ ker g
>
> 2)Ker $f= $ ker g
>
> 3) $f=kg,\forall k>0$

From above given I only get that as non zero linear function has kernel of dimension n-1 for dimenion of V is n .I do not see directly kernel of one is of other

I am not able to go beyond.

I wanted to solve this problem Just give Hint.

Thanks In Advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the hypothesis to $x$ and $-x$ to get 1). For 2) a hint is the fact that the kernels have the same codimension. For 3) let $f(x)\neq0$,take any $y$ and choose $c$ such that $f(y-cx)=0$. This means $c =\frac {f(y)} {f(x)}$. By 1) we get $g(y-cx)=0$. Hence $g(y)=cg(x)=\frac {f(y)} {f(x)}g(x)$. Write this as $g(y)=k'f(y)$ where $k'=\frac {g(x)} {f(x)}$. Clearly that $k'\neq 0$. Take $k=\frac 1 {k'}$. Can you see why $k >0$?

Comment: Dear Sir, I get first 2 but last one still I did not get last one.Please can help more? I do not understand why y-cx is in both kernal of f and g where y and c depends on x tell f=kg.  Also I got f(y)/f(x)=c=g(y)/g(x)

Comment: @SRJ I have edited the answer with details for 3).  Note that $\forall k>0$ is obviously false in 3). It should say 'for some $k >0$'.